# UIAlertView delegation - return button index to calling method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

Not sure if I worded that question correctly. Is there a way to have the button index selected in a UIAlertView returned to the method where the UIAlertView was initiated in?

So

```
- (void) someMethod { 

UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm Adding Product" message:Blah, blah, blah" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", @"No", nil];
    [alert show];

//some more code - I'd like to get the button index returned here!

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

   //anyway to return this to the method above?
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    }

}
```

Comment: No, that is why we use delegation, to delegate a certain task to another method/place. What are you trying to accomplish within `someMethod` that you cannot do in the delegate method?

Comment: Pass a value to a third method...

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot "return" anything to the method that has shown the alert view because that method has finished executing. If you want to perform an action on a specific button click, then call a new method.

```
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
      [myclass someNewMethod];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use convenient category UIAlertView+BlocksKit.h from [BlocksKit](https://github.com/pandamonia/BlocksKit)

```
- (void) someMethod {

    [UIAlertView bk_showAlertViewWithTitle:@"Title"
                                   message:@"Message"
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil
                                   handler:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {

                                       // Use buttonIndex in someMethod's context:
                                       NSLog(@"Pressed button at index %d", buttonIndex);

                                   }];
}
```